# Replace values of one dataframe from the corresponding values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two data.frames `A` (`dat1`) and `B` (`dat2`).

Is it possible to find small differences (up to `tol`) between one or more **numeric columns** (`cols`) across `A` and `B` and the replace those in `A` with the corresponding ones in `B`

For example, if you look at the numeric columns across `A` and `B`, you'll see `THIS` in `A` for column `upper.CL` is **1.770** but the same in `B` is **1.771** i.e., they are different by `tol = .001`. In this case, all we need is to replace **1.770** in `A` with **1.771** from `B` so that all numeric columns in `A` and `B` are the same.

Is it possible to write an `R` function to find & use all numeric columns that differ by `tol` and replace the values as described above?

```
foo <- function(dat1, dat2, cols = NULL, tol){

# Solution
} 

# EXAMPLE OF USE:
#### foo(dat1 = A, dat2 = B, cols = upper.CL, tol = .002)
# OR
#### foo(dat1 = A, dat2 = B, tol = .002)
```

```
A = read.table(h=TRUE, text="
  task_dif time emmean    SE lower.CL upper.CL
1  complex    1  1.733 0.023 1.686    1.779
2   simple    1  1.734 0.018 1.697    1.770# <- THIS
3  complex    2  1.702 0.025 1.652    1.751
4   simple    2  1.714 0.017 1.680    1.747
5  complex    3  1.757 0.019 1.720    1.794
6   simple    3  1.740 0.027 1.687    1.794
7  complex    4  1.773 0.019 1.735    1.810
8   simple    4  1.764 0.025 1.713    1.814")

B = read.table(h=TRUE, text="
  order time emmean    SE lower.CL upper.CL
1   c2s    1  1.733 0.023 1.686    1.779
2   s2c    1  1.734 0.018 1.697    1.771# <- THIS
3   c2s    2  1.714 0.017 1.680    1.747
4   s2c    2  1.702 0.025 1.652    1.751
5   c2s    3  1.757 0.019 1.720    1.794
6   s2c    3  1.740 0.027 1.687    1.794
7   c2s    4  1.764 0.025 1.713    1.814
8   s2c    4  1.773 0.019 1.735    1.810")
```

## Desired output:

```
A = read.table(h=TRUE, text="
  task_dif time emmean    SE lower.CL upper.CL
1  complex    1  1.733 0.023 1.686    1.779
2   simple    1  1.734 0.018 1.697    1.771# <- Replaced using corresponding value in `B`
3  complex    2  1.702 0.025 1.652    1.751
4   simple    2  1.714 0.017 1.680    1.747
5  complex    3  1.757 0.019 1.720    1.794
6   simple    3  1.740 0.027 1.687    1.794
7  complex    4  1.773 0.019 1.735    1.810
8   simple    4  1.764 0.025 1.713    1.814")

B = read.table(h=TRUE, text="
  order time emmean    SE lower.CL upper.CL
1   c2s    1  1.733 0.023 1.686    1.779
2   s2c    1  1.734 0.018 1.697    1.771# <- THIS
3   c2s    2  1.714 0.017 1.680    1.747
4   s2c    2  1.702 0.025 1.652    1.751
5   c2s    3  1.757 0.019 1.720    1.794
6   s2c    3  1.740 0.027 1.687    1.794
7   c2s    4  1.764 0.025 1.713    1.814
8   s2c    4  1.773 0.019 1.735    1.810")
```

Comment: My points in your [previous (since-deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75318911/3358272) still stand. Most notably, *"an exhaustive comparison of all numeric columns in A with all numeric columns in B (worst-case ncol(A)*ncol(B) combinations)"* and *"you need a percentage of which must be within the tolerance to consider the merge"*. I suggest that a solution that does not at least _address_ these concerns will be fragile and/or have a reasonably-high probability of false-positives. Can you add that context to your question to clarify the ambiguity?

Comment: @r2evans, my scope of use for the function is fairly limited. Pretty much what you see here is what I need. Yes, on the grand scale (i.e., any two dataframes of any size) that would be an issue.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a means to join based on two _known ids_ being within tolerance, not an arbitrary set of columns for comparison. For instance, join in `lower.CL` (both sides) being within some tolerance. Or perhaps `A$emmean` close to `B$emmean` within some tolerance. Is that correct?

Comment: @r2evans, pretty much a few rows in the last four columns occasionally don't match by a `tol = .002`. In my actual table I have 6 numeric columns.

Comment: This can be easily addressed using `fuzzyjoin` (among the others I already mentioned in the other question), but when I test some tolerance I get a 1-to-many match, which is likely not sufficient. What other join columns do you have? Lastly, using a floating-point as a joining-index is a computational problem because floating-point equality is in inexact calculation, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518, https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754.

Comment: Should `time` and/or some comparison of `task_dif` and `order` be used in the join?

Comment: @r2evans, eventually yes.

Comment: @r2evans, the data.frames are all first rounded to avoid `floating-point` problem. That part gave me  alot of pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
close <- function(tol) function(a, b) abs(a - b) <= tol
mutate(A, rn = row_number()) %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
    select(B, upper.CL), 
    by = "upper.CL", 
    match_fun = list(close(0.001))) %>%
  distinct(rn, upper.CL.x, upper.CL.y, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(-upper.CL.x, upper.CL = upper.CL.y)
#   task_dif time emmean    SE lower.CL rn upper.CL
# 1  complex    1  1.733 0.023    1.686  1    1.779
# 2   simple    1  1.734 0.018    1.697  2    1.771
# 3  complex    2  1.702 0.025    1.652  3    1.751
# 4   simple    2  1.714 0.017    1.680  4    1.747
# 5  complex    3  1.757 0.019    1.720  5    1.794
# 6   simple    3  1.740 0.027    1.687  6    1.794
# 7  complex    4  1.773 0.019    1.735  7    1.810
# 8   simple    4  1.764 0.025    1.713  8    1.814
```

Notes:

- I add `rn` in the likely condition of a 1-to-many join; if you look at the data *before* `distinct(..)` above, you'll see that rows 5 and 6 are repeated, which makes sense since `1.794` occurs twice each in `A` and `B` (though twice in one alone is sufficient for 1-to-many). Your real data might introduce more duplicate rows that `distinct` do not address, you can use `rn` to summarize/aggregate or reconstruct as needed.
- Joining on a floating-point number is not guaranteed; while it should likely work well enough with this data, the issue is never an error: failures due to floating-point equality concerns will merely evidence as "did not join", which is not an error nor even a warning. The `tol=` should address most of that, but caveat emptor.
- It seems likely that this join might also need more join-columns. For those, within `fuzzy_left_join` one would include `` `==` `` as the match function. For instance, if `time` were also a join on equality (just work with me here), then

  ```r
  mutate(A, rn = row_number()) %>%
    fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
      select(B, time, upper.CL),
      by = c("time", "upper.CL"),
      match_fun = list(`==`, close(0.001))) %>%
    ...
  ```

  (If not clear, those are backticks, not single-quotes.)
- my `close` is a function that returns a function ... that may seem too meta, but it works well in a more generalized fashion here. `match_fun` must be a function (either anonymous or named) or a `~`-function (rlang-style). I think this looks more readable than the equalalent `match_fun=list(~ abs(.x - .y) < 0.001)`, though that works as well.

---

In the end, I think this function might meet your needs.

```r
close <- function(tol) function(a, b) abs(a - b) <= tol
myjoin <- function(X, Y, by = NULL, tol = 1e-9,
                   type = c("full", "left", "right"), reduce = TRUE) {
  if (is.null(names(by))) names(by) <- by
  stopifnot(
    all(names(by) %in% names(X)),
    all(by %in% names(Y)),
    all(!is.na(tol) & tol >= 0)
  )
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (length(tol) == 1L) tol <- rep(tol, length(by))
  funs <- lapply(tol, function(z) if (z < 1e-15) `==` else close(z))
  joinfun <- switch(
    type,
    full = fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_full_join,
    left = fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join,
    right = fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_right_join)
  out <- joinfun(
    transform(X, rn = seq_len(nrow(X))),
    subset(Y, select = by),
    by = by, match_fun = funs)
  if (reduce) {
    samename <- (names(by) == by)
    byx <- paste0(names(by), ifelse(samename, ".x", ""))
    byy <- paste0(by, ifelse(samename, ".y", ""))
    out <- out[!duplicated(out[, unique(c("rn", byx, byy))]),]
    rownames(out) <- NULL
    # ASSUMING you always want to replace the LHS 'by' columns with the
    # RHS columns ...
    out[names(by)] <- out[byy]
    out[c(byx[samename], byy)] <- NULL
  }
  out
}

myjoin(A, B, by = "upper.CL", tol = 0.001, type = "left")
#   task_dif time emmean    SE lower.CL rn upper.CL
# 1  complex    1  1.733 0.023    1.686  1    1.779
# 2   simple    1  1.734 0.018    1.697  2    1.771
# 3  complex    2  1.702 0.025    1.652  3    1.751
# 4   simple    2  1.714 0.017    1.680  4    1.747
# 5  complex    3  1.757 0.019    1.720  5    1.794
# 6   simple    3  1.740 0.027    1.687  6    1.794
# 7  complex    4  1.773 0.019    1.735  7    1.810
# 8   simple    4  1.764 0.025    1.713  8    1.814
myjoin(A, B, by = "upper.CL", tol = 0.001, type = "left", reduce = FALSE)
#    task_dif time emmean    SE lower.CL upper.CL.x rn upper.CL.y
# 1   complex    1  1.733 0.023    1.686      1.779  1      1.779
# 2    simple    1  1.734 0.018    1.697      1.770  2      1.771
# 3   complex    2  1.702 0.025    1.652      1.751  3      1.751
# 4    simple    2  1.714 0.017    1.680      1.747  4      1.747
# 5   complex    3  1.757 0.019    1.720      1.794  5      1.794
# 6   complex    3  1.757 0.019    1.720      1.794  5      1.794
# 7    simple    3  1.740 0.027    1.687      1.794  6      1.794
# 8    simple    3  1.740 0.027    1.687      1.794  6      1.794
# 9   complex    4  1.773 0.019    1.735      1.810  7      1.810
# 10   simple    4  1.764 0.025    1.713      1.814  8      1.814
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Is there a way to make a function of this?

Comment: Can `by` argument take  a vector like: `by = c('emmean', 'SE', 'lower.CL', 'upper.CL')`?

Comment: Yes, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but I get the following error: `Error in if (tol < 1e-15) `==` else close(tol) : 
  the condition has length > 1` and if I leave it as `NULL`, I get the following error: `Error: No common variables. Please specify `by` param.`

Comment: That error suggests you're feeding a vector of length greater than 1 to `tol=` which has nothing to do with `by=`. I don't know how you're calling it, but I think you're calling it wrong.

Comment: Here is my call: `myjoin(A, B, by = c('emmean', 'SE', 'lower.CL', 'upper.CL'))`

Comment: Okay, I changed the defaults for both functions, source both again and try again.

Comment: I get the same error for the same call.

Comment: Yes, I see the issue, that's my bad for testing the first code block but not fully testing the second ... I'm really sorry about that. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

this might not be the fastest since equal values also get reassigned but i think its the most straight forward implementation.

```
foo <- function(dat1,dat2,tol) {
  ## Filter numerics
  O<-lapply(list(dat1,dat2),\(x) Filter(is.numeric,x)) 
  # flag differences based on tol
  ERR<-(abs(O[[1]]-O[[2]])<=tol) 
  # reassign
  dat2[names(O[[2]])][ERR]  <- O[[1]][ERR]
  dat2
}

foo(A,B,.001)
```

Answer (score 0):

If order and the size are the same, you can simply cbind(A,B[,6])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Hope this solves your problem:

```
foo <- function(A, B, cols = NULL, tol) {
  
  if (!is.null(cols)) {
    C <- abs(A[cols]-B[cols])
    idx <- C > tol
    idx
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
      if (idx[i]) {
        A[i,cols] <- B[i,cols]
      }
    }
    
    return(A)
  }
  
  num <- unlist(lapply(A, is.numeric), use.names = FALSE)  
  nn <- unlist(lapply(A, function(x) !is.numeric(x)), use.names = FALSE)  
  
  A_num <- A[,num]
  B_num <- B[,num]
  
  A_nn <- A[,nn]
  
  C <- abs(A_num-B_num)
  
  idx <- C > tol
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(A_num)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(A_num)) {
      if (idx[i,j]) {
        A_num[i,j] <- B_num[i,j]
      }
    }
  }
  
  A_new <- cbind(A_nn, A_num)
  A_new
}
```